# VPN Setup Errors

Tags: linux, osx, vpn, pptp

I'm trying to install a VPN on one of our servers for use within my campus so that we can play some games, but I appear to be getting errors when I try to connect, as shown below. Not quite sure about all this and what's going wrong, I followed this guide:

http://www.photonvps.com/billing/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=58

We are trying to use the VPN with our macs, but they seem to be encountering some authentication errors from what I have gathered. The errors below were filtered from the messages logs.

```
Sep 16 06:38:07 localhost pptpd[1550]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=611860,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Sep 16 06:38:07 localhost pptpd[1550]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
Sep 16 06:38:07 localhost pptpd[1550]: CTRL: Client 137.195.117.105 control connection finished
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pptpd[1559]: CTRL: Client 137.195.117.105 control connection started
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pptpd[1559]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pppd[1560]: Warning: can't open options file /root/.ppprc: Permission denied
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pppd[1560]: Plugin /usr/lib64/pptpd/pptpd-logwtmp.so loaded.
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pppd[1560]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pppd[1560]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pppd[1560]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Sep 16 06:38:55 localhost pptpd[1559]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
Sep 16 06:38:58 localhost pppd[1560]: Peer conner failed CHAP authentication
Sep 16 06:38:59 localhost pppd[1560]: Connection terminated.
Sep 16 06:38:59 localhost pppd[1560]: Exit.
```

Comment: Is there another entity between these two machines, like maybe a cable router, etc? It looks like some firewall/NAT somewhere is mangling your GRE, this can often be fixed by enable GRE/PPTP VPN pass through.

Comment: This is on a virtual machine on our main server, could this be affecting it?

Comment: Depends on the hypervisor. ESXi blocks various traffic by default. To even consider routing, the network adapter on the host needs to be set to permissive.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier to just do it on the host machine?

Comment: What is the host machine?

Comment: It's a server from ovh running centos 6.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another piece of networking hardware between that CentOS server and the internet?

Comment: Yes there is, but I have no working knowledge as I don't run the network.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to ask the administrator in charge of the network to passthrough GRE for your VPN.

An alternative might be to use OpenVPN instead. OpenVPN doesn't use GRE and seems to passthrough without problems with all routers that I have used.

I haven't researched it much myself, but the word on the street is that OpenVPN is more secure and stronger.